# New Aurelia build process stops build

Tags: aurelia

I have added the following ts to my build process, but it now when I run `au run --watch` it fails to fully execute:

```js
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import * as sass from 'gulp-sass';
import * as project from '../aurelia.json';
import {build} from 'aurelia-cli';

export default function processCSS() {
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var batchLocation = './webApi2ts.bat';
 return gulp.task('task', function (cb) {
  exec(batchLocation, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
  cb(err);
 });
});
```

if i change it to match one that already exists it runs fine.  Is there something wrong with mu new process?

Thanks

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: Hey @FabioLuz, no no errors it just stops.

Comment: Just realised my issue.  I had incorrectly named the function I was exporting and that was causing me issues further down the line. #doh.